# Post to Twitter by email?

Tags: twitter

Does Twitter offer a feature like "tweet by email"? (I'd like to send an email instead of a text message from my phone to tweet)

Answer (score 3):

Also consider [If This Than That](https://ifttt.com/)!

It's really a cool service that supports a huge amount of web services you can link to each other by triggers and actions.

You can for example link the e-mail trigger to the Twitter action.

**I made a recipe for you here: https://ifttt.com/recipes/56893**